# Is it possible to use the multiple scales technique to a set of coupled ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, dynamical-systems, perturbation-theory

I need to solve a set of coupled ODEs. The ODEs are well indicated for using the multiple scales method (generalised oscillator equations), I have just never done such a thing on a ODEs set. Is it possible? How should I adapt the steps?

Please note: Since there is a good chance I haven't been lucky enough finding in literature and google, I'll be really glad for an online reference as well.

EDIT: Please, provide minimal working example or a reference containing it.

Comment: It works fine. You just might have some issues with there being more than two timescales.

Comment: @Ian Could you please elaborate a bit? My mistake, I haven't been specific about the answer, the question is edited now.

Comment: Yes you can do that. "Multiple scales" or "multigrid" or "multi resolution analysis" and probably more concepts are capable to approach that. Usually a goal is to speed up the solution.

Comment: @mathreadler: "Multigrid" is quite different from e.g. "Multiple scales". [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-scale_analysis) gives an example of the latter for an oscillatory problem. But it can be proved that oscillatory problems can not at all be solved with multigrid methods. [The proof](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/origineel.htm) is too large for fitting into the margin of this comment :-(

Comment: @HandeBruijn I see. I always assumed without much reflection that they were more closely related than that. But then one day realization strikes and all illusions are shattered.

Comment: By 'solve', do you mean 'find an (approximate) analytical solution', or 'obtain a numerical solution by numerical simulation'?

Comment: @FritsVeerman Find an (approximate) analytical solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend

F. Verhulst, *Nonlinear Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems*, Springer, 2006, ISBN 978-3-540-60934-6;

starting with chapter 9, several methods of multiple scale analysis are treated, with extensive use of examples. For another slightly more general reference, see

C. Kuehn, *Multiple Time Scale Dynamics*, Springer, 2015, ISBN 978-3-319-12316-5.

Without more specific information on your system, it's difficult to give a suitable working example.

Some online resources can be found [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m204/ch6.pdf), [here](https://www.iist.ac.in/sites/default/files/people/multiplescale.pdf), [here](http://folk.uio.no/geirkp/mek3100v08mod/twoscal.pdf), or [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.3651). I recommend you use a book, though.